# Displaying ActionBar in PreferenceScreen looks messed up

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to display an ActionBar in my PreferenceScreen. In my MainActivity it works totally fine, but in my PreferenceScreen it lokks messed up, because the title of the actinBar is in the middle of the screen and the layout is placed over the actionBar (see screenshot).

SettingsActivity.java:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_drawer, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.settings_drawer);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        setNavigationViewListener();
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
```

settings_activity.xml:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace your fragment directly with the `DrawerLayout`, instead use a `FrameLayout` inside the `DrawerLayout` that you can replace your fragment with.
Something along the following lines should work.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings_drawer_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings_drawer"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**P.S** -
You'll need to reference your `DrawerLayout` with the new id I gave it.

```
mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.settings_drawer_base);
```